# Converting Timezones with momentjs and moment-timezone.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I want a person to be able to have 2 prompts.

1. Guest Timezone
2. My Timezone

I already have the guest timezone. The idea, is to convert timezones.

The Guest would his Timezone, and Mine is EST.

I have the guest timezone working, I can't make it to have another prompt to get my timezone, and convert it with moment.

Here is what I have, so far. I want to be able to prompt the other person to keep their timezone and convert Guest timezone to the My Timezone

```js
// Starts Moment
  var moment = require('moment-timezone');
  
  // Prompt to get the timezone
var prompt = prompt("What timezone") 


// Shows the time in the current timezone

var time = moment().tz(prompt).format();

// Console logs the Time
console.log(time)

// Shows the Current date, and Month
var date = moment().format('dddd'); 
var month = moment().format('MMMM');
```

There should be a way, I don't know what it is though

Comment: I'm not understanding what problem you're running into. It sounds like you want to do the exact same thing that you're doing right now, but a second time with a second set of user input. If that's the case, just prompt them again for the second timezone and run your moment code again. Also, don't use prompt as your variable name - change it to something else `var tz1 = prompt("Guest Timezone"); var tz2 = prompt("My Timezone");`

Comment: Hey Joseph!

Thanks for helping! It wasn't working, when I made another prompt! Will change and let you know!

Comment: That's likely because you're defining a new variable called "prompt" in your function - so later in your function, when you call "prompt()", it's trying to run your string (which won't work) instead of the native window.prompt() function. Changing your variable declaration to something else (`var tz1 = prompt()`) should fix that.

Comment: Yeah, It works now. Thanks Joseph, have a wonderful day!

Comment: You as well! I'll post this as an answer so you can mark the question as closed. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion, it appears the issue is being caused by overwriting the "window.prompt" method inside of your function. When you set:

```
var prompt = prompt("What Timezone")
```

You are adding a new variable called "prompt" which will take precedence over the built-in window.prompt when you use it later in your code. You should rename your variables to something more specific to their purpose (and to a unique name for each) like this:

```
// Starts Moment
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

// Prompt to get the timezone
var timezone1 = prompt("Guest Timezone");
var timezone2 = prompt("My Timezone");

// Shows the time in the current timezone
var time1 = moment().tz(timezone1).format();
var time2 = moment().tz(timezone2).format();

// Console logs the Time
console.log(time1);
console.log(time2);
```

Then, you'll have two formatted date strings (time1 and time2), one for each of the timezones.